# Scroll view doesn't scroll

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7

I use this code but it doesn't scroll. I connect UIScrollView in xib but still doesn't work. What should I do?

```
[self.scrollview1 setScrollEnabled:YES];
self.scrollview1.contentSize =CGSizeMake(320, 650);
[self.scrollview1 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.scrollview1.contentOffset.x, 0)
                                  animated:YES];
```

Comment: Doublecheck if autolayout is on.

Comment: I remove the check and still doesn't work. My scroll view in a UIView. Does it effect?

Comment: What is the size of the frame of the view the scroll view is embedded in?

Comment: 320 x 519. Height of scrollview is greater. So there should be no problem.

Comment: put a breakpoint in viewDidAppear and then type this into the debugger and copy the results here, so we can see the layout of the scrollview: `po self.scrollview1`

Comment: <UIScrollView: 0x17da7590; frame = (0 55; 320 650); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17dbe530>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17d8d8a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>